# APNS notifications on Cordova only working with production push certificate when build is in debug

Tags: ios, cordova, apple-push-notifications

I am working in a Cordova environment and building the app for iOS using TACO remote build. I have implemented push notifications using the Cordova Push Plugin and the Azure Mobile Service client plugin.

iOS requires a provisioning profile which can either be Development or Distribution. For push notifications, iOS requires a push certificate which can be created by first downloading the SSL certificate from the APP ID in the developer account, and exporting the .p12 certificate from the KeyChain Access.

I am building my app in debug mode, so logic tells me that I need a development provisioning profile and a development .p12 certificate to upload into Azure. First of all, in XCode, in the app settings, under the 'Signing' sections under the 'General' tab, I am forced to choose a provisioning profile both for Debug and also for Release. Why is this?

Also, when I upload the .p12 certificate generated from the development SSL certificate, I am able to register but not receive push notifications. When I upload the .p12 certificate generated from the production SSL certificate, I am both able to register and also receive push notifications. Why is this? All this bearing in mind that in the 'Build Settings' of the app, under 'Build Active Architecture Only', 'Debug' is set as 'Yes' and 'Release' is set as 'No'.

Some clarification would be most appreciated.